# On iOS 13 my app view show gray color view

Tags: statusbar, ios13

My app is in objective c , It is quite old app. I want to hide top bar from screen, I have hide status bar but its view is still display.
I am not sure what is it and how to hide or change color of it. I want to change color of this gray color view to white, if it is not possible then I want to hide it. 
Can any one know about it?
[image]

In Info.plist file I have "View controller-based status bar appearance" key and Set "No", "Status bar is initially hidden" key with "YES". In "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method add "[application setStatusBarHidden:YES];".

Comment: Can you share the code on where you're trying to hide it?

Comment: I have added in description. I have did from info.plist and didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.